# Mathematica.SE User Inteface Problems

Tags: support

Yesterday, I noticed that my Mathematica.SE user page sometimes was different, depending on how I reached the page.  Today, after I rebooted my computer, the appearance of nearly all Mathematica.SE pages changed.  For instance, the top part of my user page now looks like this

[image]

and the Ask page like this

[image]

Clearly, large amounts of material are missing.  I do not have this problem on other SE sites, such at Mathematica.Meta or StackOverflow.  Additionally, I do not have this problem with another Windows 10 PC that I own.  Evidently, some change occurred Friday or Saturday either on my PC or on Mathematica.SE such that the two no longer are compatible.  Does anyone else have this problem?  Is a solution known?  Thanks.

Added info.  This problem occurs for IE11 and not for Edge or Firefox.  So, it would be natural to dismiss this as just a problem with IE11, except that it does not occur with other SE cites I have tried.  Also, the Review page for Mathematica.SE looks fine on IE11.  Incidentally, clearing the IE11 cache does not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've accidentally switched to the *mobile* version of Stack Exchange. This setting is stored as a cookie in your browser (that's why you're only seeing it in IE11) and is valid per-site, so for Mathematica Stack Exchange only (that's why you're not seeing it on e.g. Stack Overflow).

You can change it back by scrolling to the bottom of the page and clicking the 'full site' link:

[image]